# System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException in C#

Tags: c#

I am doing this

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(LogFilePath()))
{
    Log1(destinationfilepath, attachmentname, sw);
}
```

to find write to a file, where logfile path is defined in my app.config file, however i get the following error,

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException:Could not find a part of the path

when running it.
Any ideas why? I've made sure that all the following file locations and log file is already there but it's not working.

log 1:

```
private static void Log1(string destinationfilepath, string attachmentname, StreamWriter sw)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(" ------------------------------");
            sw.Write("Copied over from \r\n " + attachmentname + " to " + destinationfilepath);
            sw.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
        }
```

Comment: Share the error message please. It's saying that the path is not OK, or that directory does not exists.

Comment: could you please share the `Log1` method's body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should check file or directory is existed before stream write

```
var path = LogFilePath();
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
{
    return;
}
if (!Directory.Exists(path))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
{
     Log1(destinationfilepath, attachmentname, sw);
}
```

maybe your path is null or empty or can't get from web.config